# Charting CSV files, charting solutions?

Tags: ruby, csv, charts

I am looking for charting data which is CSV. Basically it just needs to be plotted for each value of x.

Is there a good charting solution that I can use with these requirements:

1. Ability to parallelly plot multiple graphs
2. Ability to plot the graph to a file without any GUI sessions.
3. Ability to just submit data in a particular format (CSV, XML, YaML, etc.) and have it plotted out of the box.
4. Ability to overlay one graph over other.

Hopefully it is in Ruby but that is not a necessity and hopefully easy to use. I am not expecting to do any complex charting or fancy interaction with it as of now.

I am looking at lazyhighchart, but seems like you have to construct each single graph with around [10-15 LOC] rather than just submitting a CSV file to some API.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Ruport examples](http://www.rubyreports.org/examples.html).

Comment: thnx @steenslag . I am working with their examples and getting some exceptions. Looks like I cant post on their mailing list :( . Btw looks like they use Gruff underneath. Wondering how are they different than Gruff ?